# c# interface implemention - why does this not build?

Tags: c#, arrays, interface, ienumerable, implementation

Sorry if this has been asked before but it's virtually impossible to google. I think that an int array implements IEnumerable and therefore Thing should be able to implement IThing. How come it doesn't?

```
public interface IThing
{
    IEnumerable<int> Collection { get; }
}

public class Thing : IThing
{
    public int[] Collection { get; set; }
}
```

note that

```
public class Thing : IThing
{
    public int[] Array { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<int> Collection
    {
         get
         {
              return this.Array;
         }
    }
}
```

is fine.

Comment: `int[]` is not the same Type as `IEnumerable<int>` even though it implements `IEnumerable<int>`

Comment: C# does not support return-type covariance for overrides or interfaces.

Comment: Are you just trying to understand why this is not allowed (SLaks's comment is the reason), or is your goal just to provide the concrete type (`int[]`) on the class, while leaving the interface definition `IEnumerable<T>`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The interface implementation must implement the interface exactly.  This prevents you from returning a type that implements that interface as the member.

If you wish to do this, one option is to implement the interface *explicitly*:

```
public interface IThing
{
    IEnumerable<int> Collection { get; }
}

public class Thing : IThing
{
    public int[] Collection { get; set; }
    IEnumerable<int> IThing.Collection { get { return this.Collection; } }
}
```

This allows your public API for the class to use the concrete type, but the interface implementation to be fulfilled correctly.

For example, with the above, you can write:

```
internal class Test
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IThing thing = new Thing { Collection = new[] { 3, 4, 5 } };

        foreach (var i in thing.Collection)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems like an necessary restriction in c# in my opinion. Thanks very much for you answer, by explicitly implementing the interface I can do what I want to do. I can use this to implement the interface in a partial class, meaning I don't have to edit a auto-generated code file.

Answer (score 7):

For an interface to be implemented the method signature and return type must be identical, so the fact that an int[] is convertible to an IEnumerable makes no difference I'm afraid.

Answer (score 6):

The return type of the properties in the different implementations is different - returning a `int[]` is not the same as returning a `IEnumerable<int>`.

As far as implementing the interface - the types must match *exactly*.

This should work just fine:

```
public class Thing : IThing
{
    public IEnumerable<int> Collection { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your implementations should implement interface exactly as it is.

Answer (score 2):

Because the signature of

```
IEnumerable<int> Collection { get; }
```

Is not the same than the signature of

```
int[] Collection { get; set; }
```

And when you implement an interface, the signatures should be exactly the same.

Answer (score 2):

This is where covariance / contravariance can come in handy.  This feature lets you define in/out tags on your generics and lets you do the following:

```
public interface IThing<out T> where T : IEnumerable<int> {
    T Collection { get; }
}

public class Thing : IThing<int[]> {
    public int[] Collection { get; set; }
}
```

Then that will allow you to define other implementations, and then still use them together as `IThing<IEnumerable<int>>`s.

```
public class Thing2 : IThing<List<int>> {
    public List<int> Collection { get; set; }
}

class Program {
    static void Main() {
        var x = new Thing();
        var y = new Thing2();
        new List<IThing<IEnumerable<int>>> { x, y };
    }
}
```

The advantage of this approach over the explicit interface implementation is that you *guarantee* that IThing.Collection is the exact same method as Thing.Collection, whereas with explicit implementation, they're actually different methods so there's no such guarantee.  The disadvantage of course being that you have to be a little more explicit and so it makes the code a bit "noisier" to look at.

Not sure why the C# compiler couldn't figure this out implicitly; my guess being that it'd just take too long to compile with that extra check.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the definition of [Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx) you'll notice that it says "...the corresponding member of the class must be public, non-static, and have the same name and signature as the interface member."

While an array or a List implements IEnumerable, it is *not* an IEnumerable object. That's your problem.

Your signature must match for it to work. You'll notice that `public List<int> Collection { get; set; }` will not work, either. You will either need to change your Interface's property definition, or have your implementation return an `IEnumerable <int>` as you have with your second working example.