# How to implement Interface which defines element of another Interface

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, ienumerable

```
Interface A
    {
      string x {get;set;}
      IEnumarable<InterfaceB> DetailList { get; set; }
    }
    Interface B
    {
     int z;
     int y;
    }

    Class B :Interface B
    {
      implements z;
      implements y;
    }
    Class A :Interface A
    {
      implements x;
      IEnumarable<ClassB> DetailList {get;set;} // This line is giving trouble.
    }
```

Is this code violating OO concept. I thought if I derive ClassB from InterfaceB then I can use ClassB in my ClassA instead of InterfaceB. VS is not liking this, Its asking me to use InterfaceB instead of ClassB in ClassA. 
Is there any other way to go about doing this.

I am willing to consider alternate designing options, I have some domain objects whose properties are defined by Interface A and each domain object would have corresponding object defined by interface B
e.g
concert(A)  concertlocations(B)
comedyshow(A) comedyshowlocations(B)

Feel free to ask more questions if you think I am not being clear enough.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Does `DetailList` on interface A need to be publicly settable?

Comment: Yes. It has to be publicly settable, I am willing to consider alternate designing options, I have some domain objects whose properties are defined by Interface A and each domain object would have corresponding object defined by interface B
e.g
concert(A)  concertlocations(B)
comedyshow(A) comedyshowlocations(B)

Comment: Your code won't compile. But why do you want to do this? DetailList can still be of IEnum_e_rable<InterfaceB> when you want to add a ClassB instance to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can this:

```
public interface InterfaceA<T> where T : InterfaceB
{
    string x {get;set;}
    IEnumerable<T> DetailList { get; set; }
}

public interface InterfaceB
{
    int z { get; }
    int y { get; }
}

public class ClassB : InterfaceB
{
    public int z { get; private set; }
    public int y { get; private set; }
}

public class ClassA : InterfaceA<ClassB>
{
    public int z { get; private set; }

    public string x { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ClassB> DetailList {get;set;} 
}
```

but I'm not sure this is desirable for you?

see here for more info: [c# interface implemention - why does this not build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8246886/c-sharp-interface-implemention-why-does-this-not-build)

Comment: This would work for what I am trying to do, I would mark this as answer. But give second thoughts to my design.

Answer (score 2):

Interface A just says that the `IEnumarable<InterfaceB> DetailList { get; set; }` has to be present in any class, that is implementing it, with exactly `InterfaceB` being the generic type for IEnumerable, and not one of it's implementaions.

Class B is less general than Interface B, therefore it is completely logical that it does not allow you to use it in such manner.

Comment: I thought it would be an issue while I was writing it, thanks for clearing some smoke around that for me.
But is there a way to mention in Interface A that, IEnumarable<InterfaceB> DetailList { get; set; } 
can be InterfaceB or its implementation ?